# Enumerating 2 combinations of dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, iteration, combinations

I wish to enumerate over all 2 combinations of dictionary keys in python. For example if I have some dictionary like:

```
di = {'a': [1, 2 ,5], 'b': "haha", 'c': 34, 'd': 24}
```

Now, suppose each key were indexed by its order. For example `a` would be `1` `b` would be `2` and so forth.

Then we could do the familiar iteration to get all 2-combinations:

```
for i in range(len(di)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(di)):
```

However, the dictionary keys are not indexed as above. So how do I perform this iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't want special handling to split up that list keyed to 'a':

```
list(itertools.combinations(di.values(),2))
Out[6]: 
[([1, 2, 5], 34),
 ([1, 2, 5], 'haha'),
 ([1, 2, 5], 24),
 (34, 'haha'),
 (34, 24),
 ('haha', 24)]
```

(python 3 syntax)

Comment: Yes, I did this with di.keys() and it is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

[itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) could be of help.